# Eigens lazy evaluation with intermediate variable

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, eigen

In the Eigen documentation, I couldn't find an explanation of the exact circumstances under which an expression will be lazily evaluated. In my case, I'm only interested in coefficient-wise expressions (ie no possibility of aliasing).

For example, given `ArrayXXf a(10000, 10000);`

```
a = a.cube() * a.cube();
```

evaluates for me in ~250ms, the same as

```
auto aCube = a.cube();
a = aCube * aCube;
```

whereas

```
ArrayXXf aCube = a.cube();
a = aCube * aCube;
```

takes ~550ms to evaluate.

Does assigning an expression to an explicit Array type (such as ArrayXXf) always force it to be evaluated?

The code was compiled with `MinGW release -O3`.

This is intended as a general question; the example is just made-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, yes if you assign an expression to an `Array<...>` it gets evaluated explicitly (unless the compiler thinks it can optimize away that variable entirely -- that can be the case, especially for small fixed sized arrays.

Assigning to a `auto` variable does no evaluation (unless your expression ends with `(...).eval()`), that also means that `aCube * aCube` will evaluate each coeffient of `aCube` twice (although the compiler is likely smart enough to figure out that it can reuse the value). In that particular case it would perhaps be better to write `a = aCube.square();`

Comment: Does that also count for matrices? What do you then need the noalias() in a contxt like `matrix1.noalias() = matrix2 * matrix2;` documented [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) for?

Comment: Because at the time `matrix2 * matrix2` is assigned to `matrix1` it will get evaluated (unless you write `auto matrix1 = ...;`). And for matrix products, Eigen can't be sure that there is no aliasing, so by default, it evaluates into  a temporary.